# Sorting based on Continuity of Data

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity

Assuming there is a class of Data like below pseudo-code.

```
class Data
    decimal Addition
    decimal Result
end
```

And there is an array or list of Data. For example:

```
[0] --> { Addition = 0.0, Result = 60.0 }
[1] --> { Addition = -10.0, Result = 50.0 }
[2] --> { Addition = 5.0, Result = 65.0 }
[3] --> { Addition = 30.0, Result = 80.0 }
[4] --> { Addition = -20.0, Result = 60.0 }
```

The Result i-th member should be equal to the Result of the (i-1)th member + the Addition of the i-th member. In the above example, the order should be 0, 1, 3, 4, 2, like below:

```
[0] --> { Addition = 0.0, Result = 60.0 }
[1] --> { Addition = -10.0, Result = 50.0 }
[3] --> { Addition = 30.0, Result = 80.0 }
[4] --> { Addition = -20.0, Result = 60.0 }
[2] --> { Addition = 5.0, Result = 65.0 }
```

If there are 2 or more member with the same Result, then the earliest array member will be prioritized. How to do O(N lg N) sort for that type of data?

Comment: Why is that the order? Please explain what the sort criteria are in terms of the two fields.

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: Thank you for your edit @Kuz, now the question can be easily understood.

Comment: What if there are no valid entry that can satisfy the conditions?

Comment: That data is obtained from a verified database, so assume there is always a valid solution

Comment: What have **you** tried / found out so far? Share **your** ideas / findings.

Comment: I've implemented the one in the accepted answer, using binary search in array sorted by previous value and there is no problem in production

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that, the sequence must be started by data with value Addition = 0.0. We can found that by finding the previous Value for each data by using

```
PreviousValue = Addition-Result
```

for example

```
[0] --> { Addition = 0.0, Result = 60.0, PreviousValue = 60.0 }
[1] --> { Addition = -10.0, Result = 50.0, PreviousValue = 60.0 }
[2] --> { Addition = 5.0, Result = 65.0, PreviousValue = 60.0 }
[3] --> { Addition = 30.0, Result = 80.0, PreviousValue = 50.0 }
[4] --> { Addition = -20.0, Result = 60.0, PreviousValue = 80.0 }
```

And then we can O(n lg n) sort this list by its PreviousValue as follow

```
[3] --> { Addition = 30.0, Result = 80.0, PreviousValue = 50.0 }
[0] --> { Addition = 0.0, Result = 60.0, PreviousValue = 60.0 }
[1] --> { Addition = -10.0, Result = 50.0, PreviousValue = 60.0 }
[2] --> { Addition = 5.0, Result = 65.0, PreviousValue = 60.0 }
[4] --> { Addition = -20.0, Result = 60.0, PreviousValue = 80.0 }
```

After that, starting from initial node (data with value Addition = 0.0), we can use O(lg n) binary search on the sorted list to find data for the next sequence which Result is equal to current PreviousValue. Therefore, this problem can be solved with O(n + 2 n lg n) complexity

Answer (score 2):

The data is essentially a graph. Rewrite each member as from, to:

```
[0] --> { Addition = 0.0, Result = 60.0 }   --> { From =  0.0, To = 60.0 }
[1] --> { Addition = -10.0, Result = 50.0 } --> { From = 60.0, To = 50.0 }
[2] --> { Addition = 5.0, Result = 65.0 }   --> { From = 60.0, To = 65.0 }
[3] --> { Addition = 30.0, Result = 80.0 }  --> { From = 50.0, To = 80.0 }
[4] --> { Addition = -20.0, Result = 60.0 } --> { From = 80.0, To = 60.0 }
```

Label your graph nodes using the values and each member is an edge.

Now go read up on graph-traversal algorithms and Eulerian paths.